# How to attach a signal to qPixmap?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4

I'm creating an application using C++ Qt and I want to load multiple images. I would like to attach a signal to each image so that I can enable or disable them afterwards.

Any help?

Edit 1:

```
imageDlg = new QFileDialog();
imageList =  imageDlg->getOpenFileNames(this,
                         tr("Open Document"),
                         QDir::currentPath(),
                         tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg);;All files (*.*)"));


QString imageName;
int x = -50;
int y = -50;
int n = 1;
double size = imageList.size();

if(imageList.isEmpty())
    return;

scene->clear();
setCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);


foreach(imageName,imageList)
{
    double val = (n/size)*100;
    ui->progressBar->setValue((int)val);


    image.load(imageName,"4",Qt::AutoColor);

    image = image.scaled(100,100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation);
    imageNames.push_back(imageName.toStdString());

   // scene->setSceneRect(x,y,100,100);
    item = scene->addPixmap(image);
    item->setPos(x,y);
    x = x + 110;

    if(n%4 == 0)
    {
        x = -50;
        y = y + 90;
    }

    n++;
}

//ui->label_2->setText(strcat("10","image(s) loaded successfully"));
setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
ui->imageGraphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Comment: Images can't be "enabled" or "disabled". A widget displaying an image could be shown/hidden though. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I just want to get the image and then I can remove it from the imagelist or make it fadeout, etc..

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code. An image can't display itself, it needs a widget directly or indirectly. What you want to do depends entirely on how you're displaying your images which we don't know anything about.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the `QGraphicsPixmapItem*` pointers you're getting back from:

```
scene->addPixmap();
```

(Use e.g. a `QList<QGraphicsPixmapItem*>` or another container of your choice.)

These are the objects that are displayed on your scene. You can change their appearance, show or hide them, change their opacity etc. through those pointers.

Look at the documentation for [`QGraphicsItem`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html) for detailed information about how you can manipulate these items.

`QGraphicsItem` doesn't inherit from `QObject`, it doesn't have signals or slots (the classes derived from it don't either). If you want to handle mouse events, you'll need to create a custom graphics item (derived from `QGraphicsPixmapItem` for example) and re-implement the event handling functions you're interested in.

Look at the [Elastic Nodes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html) example to get a sample of how you can handle mouse events for graphics items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to attach a signal so that when I click on the image I can return it.

Comment: Updated. You can't "attach" a signal to an object. You can connect a slot to an object's signal, but if the object doesn't already emit that signal (or have that slot), you can't "pack it on".